# Opening intent on Sharing

Tags: android, share

I want to share a link so that when the other user clicks that link, it opens my app with some Intent data that I can process.

```
 Intent i= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 i.setType("text/plain");
 i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject");
 i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "xyz.com/blah");

 i.putExtra("important stuff", "important stuff");

 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));
```

I have also added this in manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data android:scheme="http" />
   <data android:scheme="https" />
   <data android:host="xyz.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

So on clicking the shared text, my app opens up. Now I want to work in my app according to the `important stuff`. However, on clicking it, (e.g. from Whatsapp), I only get the following in the received intent.

String name: `com.android.browser.application_id`

Value in key: `com.whatsapp`

How can I get back the `important stuff` I sent on the intent?

Comment: The intent extras will only go along with your share Intent and be processed by the app that is responding to that intent. When the user clicks your link, a brand new intent is created without those extras. If you need that data in your app after the link is clicked from another application, then either that app needs to send those extras (unlikely) or you need to have the relevant data in the url (`https://example.com/key/value`) for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get back the important stuff I sent on the intent?

You don't.

While you are certainly welcome to put random extras on `Intents`, do not expect other apps to do anything with them. In particular, there is nothing in [the `ACTION_SEND` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) requiring implementers of `ACTION_SEND` to do anything with random extras, let alone somehow get them back to you.

Similarly, while you are welcome to invent new HTTP headers, there is no requirement that a Web server pay attention to them, let alone send them back to you in a response.

Instead, replace `xyz.com/blah` with `xyz.com/important/stuff` (or possibly `xyz.com/blah?important=stuff`), and get the data out of the `Uri` used to start your activity. You get this `Uri` via `getIntent().getData()` in your activity's `onCreate()` method (or possibly `getData()` on the `Intent` passed to `onNewIntent()`, depending on your manifest settings and whether an existing instance of this activity already exists).

Comment: Thanks! `getData` was what I was looking for.